# Bluetooth UUID and pin request in QT

Tags: c++, qt, bluetooth

The Bluetooth UUID identifies a special Bluetooth Service I used in a Bluetoothserver, i implemented.
I also wrote in qt creator a small qml app to search for and connect to the service with that special UUID.
My question is: Can everyone connect to that service by searching for bluetooth devices in general, or are you only able to find it, if you search for that uuid?

If everyone can find it, so how can I set a pin on my Bluetoothserver and a pin request in my app in qt?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, all UUID services are available for discovery (SDP) and connections. There may be a security setting that can restrict service discovery for paired devices only. So, if a pairing prerequisite for service discovery is a sufficient restriction, you may be fine. Otherwise, you could implement your own password request and acceptance using the the new connection via your custom UUID service. For example, if a "password" or "custom protocol command" is not received within 3 seconds, your Bluetoothserver can drop the "unauthorized" connection on this service.